# In a post-apocalyptic world why would the survivors build bases instead of just using the abandoned buildings to live in?

Tags: post-apocalypse, survival, games

I'm making a survival game and a question popped up on how would I "in-game-explain" to the player that they can't just board up an abandoned building and call it home, but instead they have to gather resources and build everything themselves. It doesn't need to be a super realistic explanation, just something that is good enough so that the players don't feel "stupid" by doing everything the hard way.

Comment: I think this falls on the wrong side of having us create part of the story for you, but you could explain that buildings have decayed / are dangerous to live in, or a fire could have gutted the vast majority of the buildings in the area, or they were simply not built with the sort of security in mind that you need. However, even then, you're not really accounting for all the buildings, ever. There will be some understanding that it's simply the rules.

Comment: Possibly because bases are easier to defend or abandoned buildings aren't structurely sound and can be destroyed easily?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Building a new building maybe easier than repairing and maintaining one that has been neglected for years and was built using technology that is currently unavailable. Details vary by building. And is there an actual reason they might not occasionally find a building that is still usable?

Comment: Sometimes the old ones work well: Regardless of anything the player tries in the old building, "*It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue*"

Comment: It's more like a game building than worldbuilding. In any remotely sane world, survival means reusing what's there. There is a building? Cool, you now have a building.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### As this question is about a post-apocalyptic setting you should use that as your explanation

Depending on the specific nature of the catastrophe you could for example say that the players can't settle there because those old buildings are somehow infested with insects that attract mutants, or they are dangerous because old structures from before *the turn* are prone to collapsing at any point due to structural problems, like an earthquake damaging them. Other examples would be that there is for example the risk of radioactive material or something similar.

Furthermore it's easier to defend a place if you know where every possible exit is, where you can set up traps, when you can have control over possible choke points or making sure that the building suits the needs of your survivors, depending on how many you have and how the apocalypse affected them.

**Old buildings are just not safe anymore - building your own is the only way to make sure that it fits your requirements for survival.**

Comment: You gave me a lot of ideas and your last sentence absolutely nailed it. Thank you.

Comment: @lleewa I am glad that I could help you. Just a tip as you are new on the site: it's recommended to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer as some people *may* be discouraged from answering if they think you have found your solution. Waiting a bit might make more people look at the question, answer it and discuss the existing answers. This *may* increase the quantity and quality of the answers you receive. You can accept and unaccept as often as you like. Of course is absolutely, completely up to you whether you want to accept something and if so when and what. Just a tip.

Answer (score 4):

In Afghanistan we sometimes took over abandoned buildings as patrol bases and sometimes constructed our own. Its all dependant upon what the intended purpose is for the base and if there is already a suitable building where you need it or not. If the purpose is to provide overwatch and support for regular patrols into a wide valley to prevent weapons smuggling then it was getting built on top of a ridge overlooking the area. If the purpose is to provide a headquarters for patrols moving amongst the populace of a large town then we were probably just going to take over and retro-fit an abandoned building for our purposes.

Retro-fitting an old building vs constructing a new one is entireley dependant upon whether there are any suitable buildings present to retrofit  or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Because preapocalyptic buildings are not defensible**

Does your postapocalyptic wasteland have mutants, bandits, cannibals, or cultists? If it does then your survivors have to be able to defend themselves and civilian architecture doesn't prioritize defensibility. Just looking around the house I'm typing this from; I could easily kick down the front door and the door to the backyard is literally glass. Drywall won't stop a bullet or a sledgehammer. Drywall and vinyl siding are nice now, after the collapse you want walls that are bulletproof and fireproof complete with firing slits and a sturdy gate. A survivor doesn't want a white picket fence, he wants punji sticks.

**Because there's no electricity**

Consider a very common type of building, the big box store. Electricity is used to power the lights and the AC. This works well now, but what happens when the grid goes down? In the summer you've got a dark oven and in the winter a dark icebox. This applies to a greater or lesser extent to other kinds of buildings. Your survivors will want to build structures that are comfortable with little or no power. [This wiki article goes in depth about the kind of buildings I have in mind.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_solar_building_design)

**Because there's no running water**

A suburb or subdivision is not necessarily build on top of its water supply, but that's not a problem because as long as we have civilization we can pipe in water from elsewhere. But when there's no civilization you need a well, preferably within walking distance. And not just any well, a clean well. Even if your survivors can dig a well that produces enough water for them next to a building they took over that water could be contaminated. Especially if the building they took over was some sort of industrial site or even a gas station.

Answer (score 0):

If pre-fall buildings where able to be held against whatever killed everyone they wouldn't have died.

Vampires often are limited by invitation; in an existing structure you can't be sure who previous inhabitants have allowed, building fresh is the only way to be sure they can't waltz in.

Lots of big windows and balloon framing are popular in modern designs, but are worthless at slowing down raptor attacks. Similarly the large doors or loading docks ubiquitous in industrial and commercial buildings are not defensible with less effort then rebuilding.

Whatever the bad guys chances are current designs are not well suited to defense against them.

Answer (score 0):

/just something that is good enough so that the players don't feel "stupid" by doing everything the hard way/

1:  If your in game requirement is not passing your own "sniff test" maybe you should loosen it.  It seems reasonable (to you too!) that one could use a perfectly good old building. If I were gathering resources I would see what I could get from existing buildings. You would still need to gather resources to fortify and fix your old building up.

2. If your apocalypse involved fire that makes it easier.  A nuclear war or a dinosaur killer asteroid would burn a lot of buildings and leave them structurally unsound.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there aren't any buildings left? maybe some sort of self replicating nanomachine eaten everything man made before destroying itself?

It's a bit out there but if your going for a comical mix it might work well or maybe said nanomachine was created by an anti technology cult?